# VueJS v3: automatically add css class to any component

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

**Hi there!**

**tl;dr:**
Is there a way to configure VueJS to automatically add a CSS class to a component's DOM root?

**Detailed description:**
I wrote a plugin that determines the current Bootstrap breakpoint currently effective in the browser. This plugin provides this breakpoint as a runtime variable automatically to all components.

Now, a component could utilize `:class="currentBootstrapBreakpoint"` within it's template in order to render the breakpoint's name as a CSS class.

I wonder if there is a way to configure VueJS in a way that it automatically adds this breakpoint value as a CSS class property to all root DOM elements of all components without having to implement it manually.

So, if I write `<MyComponent />` the resulting topmost DOM node(s) of the component "MyComponent" should feature a class "xs" (or whatever Bootstrap breakpoint is currently active) automatically (without having to add the class manually).

**Thanks for taking the time to read my question! Any hints will be greatly appreciated**

Comment: I don't know your plugin implementation details, but by any chance, can you change your plugin to use vue [composables](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html) ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestions! Due to choices at our organization Vue composition API is not an option, we strictly use options API. As far as I understand are composables a sole thing of the composition API and thus are unfortunately nothing I can utilize.

Comment: In that case, can you utilize ```vue custom directive``` like in this [example](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/custom-directives.html#object-literals) ?

Comment: custom directives won't accomplish the automate requirement, right? Or do I miss something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work... :-)

My plugin registers a function that gets triggered on Browser window resize. So in the event handler method I utilize the following bit of code:

```
// this.breakpoints is a key/value object containing breakpoint names and their respective width values
let cssClasses = this.$el.className;
if (typeof cssClasses !== "string") {
  cssClasses = "";
}
cssClasses = cssClasses.split(" ");
cssClasses = cssClasses.filter(elem => Object.keys(this.breakpoints).indexOf(elem.replace(/^bootstrap\-/, '')) === -1);
cssClasses.push("bootstrap-" + this.currentBootstrapBreakpoint);
try {
  this.$el.className = cssClasses.join(" ").trim();
} catch (e) {}
```

Since this plugin gets applied automatically to all components, there might be DOM node types that don't feature the use of CSS classes or provide setters for them (e.g. SVG nodes), hence the additional checks and precautions not to trigger javascript errors.